# Django ManyToManyField FieldError in second app - Cannot resolve keyword 'xxxx into field

Tags: python, database, django

I'm trying to write an application where users can submit photos. Part of this involves voting for photos. So in my models.py I have:

`photos/models.py`

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    users_voted = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='voters', blank=True, null=True)
```

The users_voted ManyToManyField ensures that people can't vote twice. This all works fine, but at the moment I'm developing another app in the project which does MPTT comments. I want users to be able to vote each other's comments up, too. So I copied over the voting code into my commenting model:

`comments/models.py`

```
class MyMPTTComment(MPTTModel, Comment):
        parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
        cvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        users_voted = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='cvoters')
```

This creates a table in the database as expected. But as soon as I try to access it with my view.py code, I get the FieldError:

```
  def comment_vote(request):
    if request.GET.has_key('id'):
        try:
            id = request.GET['id']
            target = MyMPTTComment.objects.get(id=id)
            user_voted = target.users_voted.filter(
            username=request.user.username
            )
```

I've been scratching my head over this for a while now. Others with similar issues found that it might be to do with the times that Django loads the modules ( http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2010/04/30/django-manytomany-error-cannot-resolve-keyword-xxx-into-a-field.html ) but fiddling around with module orders to try to effect their loading times does nothing.

The error says `Choices are: ... voters`, so why can't `cvoters` be resolved?

EDIT: Adding complete error and traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /commentvote/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/photoproject/photos/views.py", line 300, in comment_vote
username=request.user.username
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 155, in filter
return self.get_query_set().filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 615, in get_query_set
return super(ManyRelatedManager, self).get_query_set().using(db)._next_is_sticky().filter(**self.core_filters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 669, in filter
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 687, in _filter_or_exclude
clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1271, in add_q
can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1139, in add_filter
process_extras=process_extras)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1337, in setup_joins
"Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'cvoters' into field. Choices are: comment_comments, comment_flags, date_joined, email, first_name, friend_set, groups, id, invitation, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, moderated_messages, password, photos, received_messages, registrationprofile, sent_messages, to_friend_set, user_permissions, userbio, username, voters
```

Django v1.5.4

Posting database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "comments_mympttcomment" ("rght" integer unsigned NOT NULL, "parent_id" integer, "level" integer unsigned NOT NULL, "lft" integer unsigned NOT NULL, "tree_id" integer unsigned NOT NULL, "cvotes" integer NOT NULL, "comment_ptr_id" integer PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE "comments_mympttcomment_users_voted" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "mympttcomment_id" integer NOT NULL, "user_id" integer NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE "photos_photo" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
...
"votes" integer NOT NULL,
"user_id" integer REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
);
CREATE TABLE "photos_photo_users_voted" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"photo_id" integer NOT NULL,
"user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
UNIQUE ("photo_id", "user_id")
);
```

Just noticed that the comments-user table does not include "REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id")", but I've no idea why. As stated above, the comments model includes the ManytoManyField exactly as the photos table does, importing from django.contrib.auth.models import User.

Comment: Please post the exact error...

Comment: Good if you post complete error and traceback.

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: Version 1.5. Sorry for not including all this important info in my question; it slipped my mind.

Comment: The users_voted field from `Photo` has two extra parameters, **blank=True, null=True**. The users_voted field from `MyMPTTComment` doesn't have these. Maybe this is the reason why it shows only `voters` and not `cvoters`.

Comment: No, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Could you post the database table definitions for both models(Photo and MyMPTTComment)?

Comment: try rearranging your imports, I had a similar issue recently where the order of imports changed what Django considered available choices

Comment: I've rearranged the imports in several different ways to no effect. ALso posted the table definitions above, I noticed that the comments user_voted table doesn't seem to reference auth user, does this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Try to add as I said before, **blank=True, null=True** to `cvoters` from `MyMPTTComment`. If it's possible, delete the four tables and synchronize the db. See whether the table definitions remain the same. The missing auth user might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hmm. I did as you said, and after syncing, the comments-users_voted table now includes '"user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id")'. However I still get the FieldError when voting for a comment.

Comment: `MyMPTTComment` has a *parent* field. Remove it temporary and delete the two tables related to comments. Resync the db after. It should work fine, as you said about the `Photo` model.

Comment: I did as you said, completely removing MPTT from the comments, taking out the parent field and only subclassing from django.contrib.comments.models. I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you make a sample project with the minimum information/configuration and put it online for downloading?

Comment: @Tennant strange that the error occurs when it's accessing `request.user.username`. Did you use `cvoters` property anywhere else in your codebase?

Comment: @Bibhas - no, it's not used anywhere else. I agree that it's strange. Seitaridis, that seems like a good idea. I'll do that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the use of multiple inheritance in `MyMPTTComment`. Remove the `Comment` from model's definition:

```
class MyMPTTComment(MPTTModel):
        parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
        cvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        users_voted = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='cvoters')
```

You can add again the *parent* field. I found a similar implementation to what you want to do [here](http://codeblogging.net/blogs/1/3/).

Comment: I don't think that it's this. I already tried inheriting from only Comments with no MPTT inheritance, and I still got the problem. Plus that tutorial seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to filter on a queryset Manager and not on a field. When you say:

```
users_voted = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='cvoters')
```

You are asking for Django to add a manager called `cvoters` to User instances, not a new field to the User model.

I quote from [Document how related_name affects QuerySet filtering](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10913).

Therefore, since cvoters is not a field, you cannot filter on it. Rather, you filter on the actual field you are interested in.

Comment: Hi Raydel. I tried changing the name already, and I still got the problem. Plus it doesn't explain why it works for the photo model, which uses the related name in the same way.

Comment: Is not a name problem. Are you applying some filter in the photo model that involve the `voters` manager? If not that's way in photo model works.